# OpenWindow-Opens two windows on one click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

when I click on the following button it opens up the page twice. I can not seem to find the error:

the .cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         btnPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "openWindow(" + Request.QueryString["cId"].ToString() + "," + Request.QueryString["aId"].ToString() + ");");
     }
}
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Function To Open A New Window To View the selected PDF
    function openWindow(cId, aId) {
        window.open("printMe.aspx?cId=" + cId + "&aId=" + aId + "", "", "", "");
    } 
</script>
```

and the button in the aspx:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Image-Url="~/images/print.bmp" ToolTip="Printer Friendly Page">
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to `return false;` at the end of the onclick-event? Also, `+ aId + "",` looks unnecessary, you could just replace it with `+ aId,` (remove the empty string).

Comment: Debug with a `console.log` in javascript to verify that your function is being called only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the javascript like below fixed the problem. I am no expert at javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Function To Open A New Window To View the selected PDF
    function openWindow(cId, aId) {
        window.open("printMe.aspx?cId=" + cId + "&aId=" + aId,"mywindow");
    } 
</script>
```